# Running a python file on the button click in Node JS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, express

I am trying to run a python file (which is actually running a Deep learning model) on a button click using Node JS. I am trying to achieve this using input form in html and routes in index.js file. But this is causing this error after running for a while:

[image: error]

**I just want to run the python file in the background, no arguments, no input or output.**

This is my index.html file:

```
<form action="/runpython" method="POST">
  <button type="submit">Run python</button>
</form>
```

And this is my index.js file:

```
function callName(req, res) {
  var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

  var process = spawn("python", ["denoising.py"]);

  process.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    res.send(data.toString());
  });
}

app.post("/runpython", callName);
```

**Note: This works fine if I have simple print statement in my .py file**

```
print("Hello World!")
```

But running below code in .py file creates an issue

```
"""# import modules"""


"""# loading previously trained model"""

import noisereduce as nr
import numpy as np
import librosa
import librosa.display
import IPython.display as ipd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import load_model
import soundfile as sf
model = load_model(
    r'model/denoiser_batchsize_5_epoch_100_sample_2000_org_n_n.hdf5', compile=True)

"""# testing on real world audio 

"""

# function of moving point average used for minimizing distortion in denoised audio.


def moving_average(x, w):
    return np.convolve(x, np.ones(w), 'valid') / w


# audio , sr =  librosa.load(r'real_world_data/noise speech.wav' , res_type='kaiser_fast')
audio, sr = librosa.load(r'real_world_data/winona.wav', res_type='kaiser_fast')
# audio, sr =  librosa.load(r'real_world_data/babar.wav', res_type='kaiser_fast')
# audio, sr =  librosa.load(r'real_world_data/sarfaraz_eng.wav', res_type='kaiser_fast')

print(audio)
print(len(audio))
ipd.Audio(data=audio, rate=22050)

real_audio_spec = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

img = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(
    real_audio_spec, ref=np.max), y_axis='log', x_axis='time', ax=ax)

ax.set_title('Power spectrogram input real audio ')

fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format="%+2.0f dB")

ipd.Audio(data=audio, rate=22050)

start = 0
end = 65536

print(len(audio))
print(len(audio)/22050)

split_range = int(len(audio) / 65536)
print(split_range)

predicted_noise = []
input_audio = []
for i in range(split_range):

    audio_frame = audio[start:end]
    input_audio.append(audio_frame)
    audio_reshape = np.reshape(audio_frame, (1, 256, 256, 1))

    prediction = model.predict(audio_reshape)

    prediction = prediction.flatten()

    predicted_noise.append([prediction])

    start = start + 65536
    end = end + 65536


predicted_noise = np.asarray(predicted_noise).flatten()
input_audio = np.asarray(input_audio).flatten()
real_pred_noise_spec = np.abs(librosa.stft(predicted_noise))

"""## input audio to model"""

ipd.Audio(data=input_audio, rate=22050)

sf.write('input_audio.wav', input_audio.astype(np.float32), 22050, 'PCM_16')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

img = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(
    real_pred_noise_spec, ref=np.max), y_axis='log', x_axis='time', ax=ax)

ax.set_title('Power spectrogram pred noise of real audio ')

fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format="%+2.0f dB")
ipd.Audio(data=predicted_noise, rate=22050)

sf.write('predicted_noise.wav', predicted_noise.astype(
    np.float32), 22050, 'PCM_16')

ipd.Audio(data=moving_average(predicted_noise, 8), rate=22050)

denoised_final_audio = input_audio - predicted_noise
real_denoised_audio_spec = np.abs(librosa.stft(denoised_final_audio))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

img = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(
    real_denoised_audio_spec, ref=np.max), y_axis='log', x_axis='time', ax=ax)

ax.set_title('Power spectrogram final denoised real audio ')

fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format="%+2.0f dB")

ipd.Audio(data=denoised_final_audio, rate=22050)

sf.write('denoised_final_audio_by_model.wav',
         denoised_final_audio.astype(np.float32), 22050, 'PCM_16')

"""## moving point average of the real world denoised signal"""

real_world_mov_avg = moving_average(denoised_final_audio, 4)
print(real_world_mov_avg)
print(len(real_world_mov_avg))
ipd.Audio(data=real_world_mov_avg,  rate=22050)

"""## noise reduce library"""

# !pip install noisereduce

"""### nr on real world audio"""

# if you cant import it. than you need to install it using 'pip install noisereduce'

"""#### using noise reduce directly on the real world audio to see how it works on it. """

reduced_noise_direct = nr.reduce_noise(
    y=audio.flatten(), sr=22050, stationary=False)
ipd.Audio(data=reduced_noise_direct, rate=22050)

sf.write('denoised_input_audio_direct_by_noisereduce_no_model.wav',
         reduced_noise_direct.astype(np.float32), 22050, 'PCM_16')

"""#### using noise reduce on model denoised final output. to make it more clean."""

# perform noise reduction
reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(y=real_world_mov_avg.flatten(
), sr=22050, y_noise=predicted_noise, stationary=False)

# wavfile.write("mywav_reduced_noise.wav", rate, reduced_noise)
ipd.Audio(data=reduced_noise, rate=22050)

sf.write('denoised_final_audio_by_model_than_noisereduce_applied.wav',
         reduced_noise.astype(np.float32), 22050, 'PCM_16')

print("python code executed")
```

**If there is any alternative, then please let me know. I am new to Node JS and this is the only workable method I found**

Comment: `process.stdout.on("data")` may be triggered multiple times. But you are calling `res.send` every time it is triggered, which will also send the response headers multiple times. That is not allowed. Wait until your process is finished and collect the data in the meantime. Once the process has ended, send all data in one go.

Comment: @derpirscher understood, but not on the implementation level. Can you please tell me what changes should I make? I am stuck at this part from 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `res.send(data.toString());`, I don't see any use of this line in your code. Try removing the mentioned code and run again.